# SQLite for Scala

Tags: sqlite, scala

Try [googling for "scala" and "sqlite"](http://www.google.com/search?q=scala+sqlite). You don't come up with much. How are people interfacing with SQLite using Scala?

Comment: The state of the art may have changed for this question during the last 2.5 years. What is the protocol in stack overflow to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Scala runs on the JVM, it's possible to use Java libraries from Scala. So one option is to use a Java library. There are some listed on the [SqliteWrappers](https://www.sqlite.org/java/raw/doc/overview.html?name=0a704f4b7294a3d63e6ea2b612daa3b997c4b5f1) page on the SQLite wiki.

Comment: There are so many SQLite wrappers for Java, how to choose one? Would you recommend some of the best? Is there a table available comparing them?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't like the Java wrappers, so I wrote a new one in Scala.  Very alpha.  But maybe useful:

http://github.com/srhea/scalaqlite